# Kubernetes: Setting --token-auth-file

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes, token, google-kubernetes-engine, rbac

I'am using GKE, as i understood the kubernetes master is managed by google, tried to find a way to ssh into it and do some changes but with no luck,

Anyway i'am trying to use Kubernetes Role Based access control and [static token file](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/authentication/#static-token-file) authenticating, in order to do this, the API server(aka master) needs to be launched with the --token-auth-file=SOMEFILE option

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to add that command line parameter to the kubernetes master apiserver because, as you've pointed out, it's managed by google. Stick with RBAC!